# Type guard: every type except a certain type

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I am trying to create a type guard for a function that allows type parameter `T` to be any type that is *not* a `Function` like this:

```js
type Thunk<T> = (() => T) | T;

function unthunk<T extends Exclude<any, Function>>(x: Thunk<T>): T
{
    if (typeof x === "function") return x();
    return x;
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> **TS2349** Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(() => T) | (T & Function)' has no compatible call signatures.

How can I get my intended result? I am using TypeScript 3.4.

**Edit:** It seems that the `typeof x === "function"` is causing the *error*, and I can work around that by simply casting `x`. However, the type guard still does not work:

```js
function unthunk<T extends Exclude<any, Function>>(x: Thunk<T>): T
{
    if (typeof x === "function") return (x as () => T)();
    return x;
}

unthunk<() => number>(() => () => 3); // there should be an error here but there is none
```

Comment: Note that the type `Exclude<any, Function>` is equivalent to just `any`.  The `Exclude<T, U>` type only really filters union types.  It is not a true [type subtraction](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183), although that feature *may* be introduced in TS3.5 (it's on the [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#35-may-2019))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't function overload do what you want

```
function unthunk<T>(x: () => T extends Function ? never : T): T;
function unthunk<T>(x: T extends Function ? never : T): T;

function unthunk<T>(x: T): T {
    if (typeof x === 'function') { 
        return x();
    }

    return x;
}

const a = unthunk(1);
const b = unthunk(() => 1);
const c = unthunk(() => () => 1);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20unthunk%3CT%3E(x%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20T%20extends%20Function%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T)%3A%20T%3B%0Afunction%20unthunk%3CT%3E(x%3A%20T%20extends%20Function%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T)%3A%20T%3B%0A%0Afunction%20unthunk%3CT%3E(x%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20x%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function')%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20x()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20unthunk(1)%3B%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20unthunk(()%20%3D%3E%201)%3B%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20unthunk(()%20%3D%3E%20()%20%3D%3E%201)%3B)